# Creating PrimeFaces dialog dynamically in JavaScript and passing some data

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am working on a simple messenger using JSF and PrimeFaces. I would like to have contact list in the right part of the window and multiple conversation dialogs in the second part. Dialog will contain just a send button, an input and conversation content.

#### Use case:

User #1 clicks on contact, chat dialog appears. User #2 is logging to system. System checks that he has 1 unread message so it opens chat dialog. User #2 clicks on another contact and second chat dialog appears.

#### Questions:

1. How to pass some context to dialog like user-you-are-writing-to's ID so when you click on send button in this particular dialog you will be able to access it?
2. Is it possible to create a PrimeFaces dialog dynamically from JavaScript> Or maybe there is better solution to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a chat application you have to use a **Push Server** (and WebSockets) which would be the best solution because you have to create a `channel` between the user/client and the server (since a simple request is stateless) - and that's what push does. `PrimeFaces Push uses a servlet as a dispatcher`. This servlet should be in a different application than the JSF application and at the moment can only be deployed on `jetty` server.

You could read about this in **Primefaces UserGuide 3.0.M4**: http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html
 and see this implementation in showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/push/chat.jsf

Another implementation/example: http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-websocket-chat

Comment: Well, you doesn't really answer my questions. Messenger is just a context of my problem which is creating dialogs from JavaScript. By the way, thank you for the information you provided but I think for a little number of users, storing messages in database and using ajax poll in client would be enough.

Comment: @rotman strictly to your problem, you do not have to create a dialog dynamically...you just have to implement a dialog component and show it everytime you need(some render attribute set to false and an update would be enough)...explain me more, if I haven't understood you problem.